# Unity - 3D blocks of prefab slightly in other position after instantiation - wobbling up

Tags: unity-game-engine, instantiation

I want to use placeholder objects within my level design and replace the placeholders by different prefabs (based on player progress) during runtime.

My problem is, that the the single blocks of my prefab do not have the correct position after I instantiate my prefab.

This is my starting position (the visible Goal_0,5 is just for demonstration here):
[image]

And this is the situation after starting the scene:
[image]

As mentioned already within the picture I found out that the y position of each row is about 0,01 too low per row (= ~0,04 at the top row) after the instantiation which causes a wobble up effect after the game starts.

I compared different values of the position of my prefab, the single blocks, the placeholder but I cannot identify the cause of this problem.
Hope you can help me.

EDIT:

This is the code used for the instantiation:

```
    private void ReplaceGoal()
{
    // Find all the game objects with the tag "placeholder_goal"
    GameObject[] placeholderObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("placeholder_goal");
    Debug.Log("placeholderGoalObjects size: " + placeholderObjects.Length);

    // Loop through the game objects and add them to the list
    foreach (GameObject placeholderObject in placeholderObjects)
    {
        GameObject instantiatedPrefab = Instantiate(prefab_goal, placeholderObject.transform.position, placeholderObject.transform.rotation);
        instantiatedPrefab.SetActive(true);
        Destroy(placeholderObject);
    }
}
```

Furthermore I recorded a video in order to show you all relevant details (e. g. the rigidbody of the blocks) and the problematic behavior more easily:
https://youtu.be/3UEoXgrEK88
The "wobbling" can be seen after I continue the app at around 0:29.

Comment: Please share the code where you instantiate the prefab.  --- Also, if I understand correctly, the prefab contains many blocks, and when instantiated, they have a slight downwards movement. Do the individual blocks have rigidbodies, as they may just be using gravity and settling into position when you instantiate. -- But yeah, you need to share the relevant code, otherwise it is difficult for anyone to offer you any aid.

Comment: Hey @DylanT25, your right. I added the relevant method and additionally a screen video where you can see many more details and the problematic behavior.

Comment: Great! Glad to hear you got it working. Happy Coding!

Comment: Oh no, that was a misunderstanding.  I still have the problem. I just updated my initial post with the requested code and additionally a video